# How can i declare or set an auto value changeable boolean variable in twincat 3

Tags: twincat

I am new to TwinCAT programming. I want to set 4 boolean variables in TwinnCAT 3 and they will change value automatically after 150 milliseconds using structured text. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use a [TON](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_standard/74406539.html?id=4250055966004209897)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change values just for once after execute the timer, basicly you can use like this;

```
PROGRAM MAIN
VAR
    bExecute : BOOL;
    bVar1    : BOOL;
    bVar2    : BOOL;
    bVar3    : BOOL;
    bVar4    : BOOL;
    Timer1   : TON; 
END_VAR
```

Define variables as above,
write your code as  below;

```
Timer1(IN:= bExecute, PT:=T#150MS);

IF Timer1.Q THEN
    bVar1 := NOT bVar1; 
    bVar2 := NOT bVar2;
    bVar3 := NOT bVar3; 
    bVar4 := NOT bVar4;
    bExecute := FALSE; // After executing, if you want to make false the bExecute variable and make Timer.IN false.
END_IF
```

For more information about `Timers` please visit [here](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_standard/74403595.html&id=)

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried and it works. Many many thanks